# How to get the object reference of a HTML element for jQuery use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A div container open nicely to fit the overflow content.
It works.
But how do I connect the reference of the triggered HTML element with jQuery.
There should be a better way than this `$("#"+divId)`

I got this code:

```
$('.text').mouseenter(function() {

//var $id = $(this); ?
//var $id = document.getElementById(divId); ?
var divId = this.id;
    var $id = $("#"+divId);

var overflow = $id.prop("scrollHeight");

this.divHeight = $id.height();

$id.animate({height:overflow},1000);
});

.text{
color: #000000;
background-color: #ffffff;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100px;
position: relativ;}


<div  class="text" id="text1">
<content>
</div>
<div  class="text" id="text2">
<content>
</div>
<div  class="text" id="text3">
<content>
</div>
```

PS Why is `$(this).height()` working but this is not `$(this).prop("scrollHeight")` ?

Thanks for help understanding.

Comment: So you want to get `this` as a jQuery Collection right ? `$this = $(this);` ... More details here `=>`[api.jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: no collection, just the $ reference to the event triggered div element. So I can use it as a Selector for the element (e.g. $("#text1"))

Comment: You can call it whatever you like, in fact it is a reference to the div having the "mouseenter" listener.@Pek

Comment: @f00bar ´$(this)´ equals to ´$("#text1")´ if the div with the id is hovered?

Comment: Don't know why, but it works know with `var $id = $(this);`  Thanks!

Comment: As a conclusion, inside the event handler, `$(this)` returns a encapsulated reference to the element which subscribed to the event. Note that when dealing with delegation, `$(this)` might be different from `$(e.target)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

**CHANGE THIS**

```
var divId = this.id;
var $id = $("#"+divId);
```

**TO**

```
var $id = $(this);
```

Comment: Works for $(this).height()  but not for $(this).prop("scrollHeight")

Comment: what you get on scrollHeight

Answer (score 0):

```
   Use jquery method like this
    $(this).prop("scrollHeight");
```